# how to assign url to words which make part from text translated with Zend_Translate?

Tags: zend-framework, hyperlink, zend-translate

I am using Zend Framework and Zend_Translate, Array adapter.
Let's say I have the following article: `"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur"` and translations of it in the languages I will use on my web site. The words `quisquam`, `dolorem`, `consectetur` represent links. I would like to echo the whole article in my view script, with the code: `echo $this->translate->_('someArticle');`. But obviously mentioned words won't be displayed as links. Is it possible to somehow scan a view script for those words that represent links, to be displayed as such using url declared for example in the respective controller? Or do I have to translate by pieces before and after words that are links? Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I've found so far is to insert links inside translations.
Example: 
In the view script: `echo $this->translate->_('someArticle');`
in translation file (array adapter): `"someArticle" => "Neque porro quisquam est qui <a href=\"/ControllerName/methodName\">dolorem</a> ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur"`
That's it: dolorem will be displayd as link. Just do not forget to escape "" with back slash.